# Issue terminating the program correctly using errx()

Tags: c, linux, error-handling

Attempted using if statements to terminate the program and output error messages before running the rest of the program: however, the printf statments follow after errx is called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(){
    printf("\nEnter an integer: ");
    int age;
    if(age){
        scanf("%d", &age);
        printf("\nEnter a real number: ");
        float percent;
        scanf("%f", &percent);
        if(percent){
            printf("\nEnter an integer: ");
            int semesters;
            scanf("%d", &semesters);
            if(semesters){
                printf("\nHenry wanted to be a TA since he was %d years old!\nLittle did he know that he would sacrifice %.2f%% percent of his day.\nSo Henry quit suddenly after %d semesters as a TA...\n", age, percent, semesters);

                errx(0,"\nProgram was completed without errors");
            }
            else{
                errx(1,"Error reading input");
            }
        }
        else{
                errx(1, "Error reading input");
        }
    }
    else{
        errx(1,"Error reading input");
```

As you can see I have 3 if statements checking input values, but If I try to run this on Linux with the following input:

```
Enter an integer: [

Enter a real number:
a.out: Error reading input
Enter an integer:
```

The program terminates after the first input of "[" but what follows it I don't really understand. Why were the print statements called and why is the error message *after* the second printf statement?

Comment: You need to `fflush` each output to  make them appear in the correct sequence, because there isn't a newline at the end. Note too that you output 3 identical messages, so it can't be seen *which* one was executed.

Comment: `int age; if (age)` is using an uninitialized variable and its behavior is undefined.

Comment: ... similarly with the other two inputs `float percent;` and `int semesters`. Always check the value returned by `scanf` (the number of successful conversions), *before* you test the data itself. If `scanf` could not convert the input, it's useless to verify the data.

Comment: Ah, did you mean to put the `if (age)` after the `scanf("%d", &age);`? Anyway, that's not quite how you do error checking for scanf, you should be looking at its return value instead.

Comment: Thank you both. I didn't think I should be checking with the scanf function's return value. That makes alot of sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int age;
if(age){
```

The variable `age` was never initialized, so the subsequent test uses the value of an uninitialized variable and thus triggers undefined behaviour.

The `scanf()` function returns the number of conversions successfully performed. Better code would check for it:

```
// scanf("%d", &age);
   if (scanf ("%d", &age) != 1) {
      fputs ("Error: Invalid input.\n", stderr);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
```

The data buffered by `printf()` is flushed when `fflush (stdout)` is called, or when the program terminates. If `stdout` is line-buffered (which is usually the case when the stream is connected to a terminal/console), then the stream will also be flushed when a newline character is encountered. But since the program invokes undefined behaviour, no assumption about the continuation of the execution of the program can be made.
Add a newline in the calls to `printf()`, or call `fflush (stdout);`.

*You need to fflush each output to make them appear in the correct sequence, because there isn't a newline at the end. Note too that you output 3 identical messages, so it can't be seen which one was executed.* –
Weather Vane